# Destroying KVM first try virtual machine

Tags: virtualization

I'm trying to understand how KVM works, working on ubuntu 10.04 server.

I created one with `sudo ubuntu-vm-builder kvm lucid --arch 'amd64'  --mem '512'  --rootsize '10248'  --swapsize '1024'  --kernel-flavour 'server'  --hostname 'testuser'  --mirror 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu'  --components 'main'  --name 'Test U'  --user 'testuser'  --pass 'passIused'`

First, it created it in `root/ubuntu-kvm` , next time I will choose wiser path

Second, I forgot to add `--libvirt qemu:///system`, so it is not showing up on virsh

**I want to delete it!**

But how? Documentation lists some options under virsh, but I it is not showing up there.

anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the /root/ubuntu-kvm directory and its contents.